# ExifTool Dates and British Summer Time / Daylight Savings

Tags: metadata

From my [previous question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/insert-exif-dates-from-file-modified-date) I am using the following ExifTool command to add Exif Date info to some photo.

`exiftool -v "-FileModifyDate>AllDates" *`

However, since we went back to GMT from BST, if I try use this on a photo which was taken during BST the Exif Dates are now all out by 1 hour. Photos taken after the switch are fine

e.g. after running ExifTool:

Photo taken BST, modified time of 11:00, Exif DateTimeOriginal is 10:00

Photo taken GMT, modified time of 11:00, Exif DateTimeOriginal is 11:00

Is this expected behaviour? Is there an override switch which will force exiftool to honour the exact modified date/time and ignore timezone differences?

EDIT: I'm using the Windows version of ExifTool

Answer (score 3):

You know, I bumped into something like this a few days ago.

I decided that from here on out, all my cameras will be set to UTC no matter where I am or whether it's daylight savings time.

Then, there won't be any need to figure out what time zone a given timestamp is in, or deal with changing the camera's clock when daylight time starts or ends. (FWIW, I went to make the latter change only to discover that it was still set to the time zone I had put in for a trip months ago. That's what prompted the decision.)

Comment: This is more and more inconvenient the farther from the prime meridian you are, because if you're off by more than a few hours, the date on the photograph will often be off by a day. For this reason, I do the same thing but using EST (never EDT) as my base.

Comment: Date and Time is a common source of problems for software, and the general advise is to store in UTC, and then render to the right timezone.

I suppose EXIF doesn't make that easy.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can set the `TZ` environment variable to GMT (or whatever), and that will be honored by every program. Either `export TZ=GMT` in the shell before you run the commands, or else prefix each one — `TZ=GMT eduction -v ...`

This should work on Mac OS X as well. I only have a vague outdated notion of Windows, but documentation suggests [the same thing should work there](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/BSM/SC32-9084-00/en_US/HTML/bsmd156.htm).

It's a shame the standard doesn't encode the timezone!