# What's a good batch-mode EXIF data editor?

Tags: software, metadata, batch, scanner

I'm currently scanning a lot of old slides. The scanner I use has this annoying habit of adding "My beautiul picture" in a description field in the EXIF format.

I'd like to use an EXIF editor to get rid of that stupid message on each file, and add actually useful data, like the date I actually shot those pictures. Ideally, this should be able to work in batch mode (I have hundreds of those files).

What do you use?

Comment: Related but more specific: [Is there any software which will set the EXIF Dates based on the file's modification date?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/is-there-any-software-which-will-set-the-exif-dates-based-on-the-files-modifica/)

Answer (score 6):

Exif has two fields to store an image description: `XPTitle` and `ImageDescription`. What field your scanner use?

The below command line (via [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)) will erase all of your `Exif:Description` and `Exif:XPTitle` fields of the images in the specified directory:

```
exiftool.exe -exif:ImageDescription= -exif:XPTitle= "YOURDIR"
```

Although any decent photo management tools like our free [Daminion](http://daminion.net) or [Lightroom](http://adobe.com)
can do this job.

Answer (score 4):

I use [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) for simple things like this. `jhead -dc file.jpg` will delete the comment field, or you can use `jhead -cl "new comment" file.jpg` to replace it. It also has a number of options for setting time and date, including taking the new EXIF date from the file's timestamp, or else setting it from the command line.

It's open-source software and comes with pre-built versions for Linux, OS X, and Windows. It's pretty simple, but *is* a command-line tool, so if you'd prefer a GUI solution you should look elsewhere. As a CLI program, though, it's nice for scripting so you can automatically fix all of your images every time you import.

If you have more complex needs, [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) is much more powerful — and complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I like Geosetter - it can touch far more exif data than just location-related tags, it works on batches of files and it is free.

It wraps ExifTool so you get a more easy-to-use interface.