# How do I automate adding EXIF date information based on the photo's filename?

Tags: metadata, batch

So recently i moved all my photos to Google Photo from a dropbox backup and while moving i realized i have around 1000+(out of several thousands of) photos which don't have valid created/modified date. It took the date from the day i moved them to google photos which is very surprising. May be dropbox removed those exif information some how. I really wan't to get the dates back because that will help me sort things up easily and also lot of memories are associated with these pics. 
The only way that information is available now is on the file name. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

Is there a automated way/software which can help me with this, may be take the file name, convert to date and time and put it to meta data? TIA.

Comment: Are you sure the EXIF info actually changed? That looks like it might just be filesystem creation/modification dates.

Answer (score 1):

I am rather certain, that you have not got to do anything.

Because I think you are confusing EXIF dates with the dates of when the picture file was created. They are independent. The dates you are showing in your screen shot, are the creation and modification dates of the file, which are meaningless. What you are interested in is the creation date in the EXIF data. The info screen from the Finder (which I think you are showing) does not show this.

To see more of the EXIF data (including the creation dates) open the file with Preview and choose "Show Inspectore" from the "Tools" menu. Then click on the EXIF tab.[image: See screenshot].

You then should see if the date corresponds to the one in your filename. I am pretty sure that they will be the same and that you do not have to do anything.

On the other hand should the date be wrong, I agree with earlier answers that you should look into the EXIF tool.

Answer (score 0):

@KD, you should check out the EXIF Tool for this job. 
If you are unix environment, then I suggest you check out this article that solves your problem: http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/433

Or check out this stackexchange thread [Is there a free program to (batch) change photo file's date to match EXIF?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27245/is-there-a-free-program-to-batch-change-photo-files-date-to-match-exif)