# How to efficiently stop metadata being in my photos?

Tags: canon, metadata

For privacy reasons, I would like to ensure that any photos I publish do not have any metadata in them. At the moment, I'm deleting the EXIF data via copy-and-paste in Photoshop, which is a very tedious process. Is there a way to:

- Stop my camera (Canon Rebel T6) from saving the metadata in the first place?
- If that can't be done, more efficiently delete the metadata?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer to the question. I've tried to edit your question so that it now expresses the general problem you were trying to solve, but if you feel it no longer represents your question then please feel free to revert it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Others have already pointed out it is pretty much impossible to do in-camera unless the camera is a smartphone or really old and already does not record EXIF it at all.***

Now for a solution that's workable and might not be such a hassle.

*I presume you own a computer and do not just go to your customers, SD card/flash disk/camera at hand.*

If so, there are very many programs/applications that allow you to strip metadata from images **in batches** (many images at once).

[Google search for "batch remove metadata images"](https://www.google.com/search?q=batch%20remove%20metadata%20images) and select some application that does that.

My personal recommendations (no relation to any of the products at all) are **exiftools** and the solutions offered in [This superuser.com question (How can I remove the EXIF tags/metadata from several images at once?)](https://superuser.com/questions/556469/how-can-i-remove-the-exif-tags-metadata-from-several-images-at-once).

Integrate the step of removing the metadata just after copying them from the camera.

Answer (score 11):

Your camera does not have the option to disable Exif. I know of no camera that has the ability to enable and disable the saving of metadata.

Some old cameras from the 1990s do not save Exif metadata.

Some phone camera apps also do not save Exif metadata. This is usually considered a bug.

---

To strip metadata after copying the files to your computer:

- See  [Is there a free program to (batch) change photo file's date to match EXIF?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/27245/75526)
- ExifTool: `exiftool -all= .`
- jpegoptim ([win32 binaries](https://github.com/vikas5914/jpegoptim-win/releases)): `jpegoptim -s *.jpg`

Answer (score 4):

I know no camera where you can suppress writing metadata to the image. However, you can easily remove it afterwards.

If you only want to strip the metadata from a single image, you can do that for example via the windows explorer:

- right click and select properties
- go to tab "details"
- select "Remove Properties and Personal Information" at the bottom
- you can then select what to remove

There are also third party tools like FileMind QuickFix for windows or ImageOptim for mac if you need to strip a batch of files. Note: I have not tested any of them.

Comment: to strip metadata in batch you'll need to use some tools like exiftool