# Set "Create Date" to "Last Modified Date"

Tags: metadata

I have a few thousand photos in which I need to set "Create Date" to "Last Modified Date", is there any tool that can help me do it automatically?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this? What is the source of the images? Why do you expect the modified date to be more accurate than the creation date? Are you referring to Exif tags or file system dates? To manipulate Exif metadata, the standard tool is `exiftool`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any software which will set the EXIF Dates based on the file's modification date?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/is-there-any-software-which-will-set-the-exif-dates-based-on-the-files-modifica)

Comment: Related: [Is there a free program to (batch) change photo file's date to match EXIF?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/27245/15871) Most of the tools listed in answers there can also do the obverse which you are seeking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are tools such as [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/), shown below.

[image: Bulk Rename Utility]

One could also [create a simple PowerShell script](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-modify-file-access-time-stamps/) to do the job, using two methods of `System.DateTime`, `LastAccessTime {get}` and `CreationTime {set;}`.